# Multi Label Annotator agreement with Cohen Kappa

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kappa

Say that I want to have annotations for documents. Every document can be annotated with multiple labels. In this example, I have 2 annotators (a and b), and they each label two documents.

```
from sklearn.metrics import cohen_kappa_score
annotator_a = [ 
    ["a","b","c"],
    ["d","e"]
]
annotator_b = [
    ["b","c"],
    ["f"]
]
```

Annotator_a labels document 1 with labels a, b and c. Annotator_b labels documents 1 with labels b and c.

I tried to calculate annotator agreement using:

```
cohen_kappa_score(annotator_a, annotator_b)
```

But this results in an error:

```
ValueError: You appear to be using a legacy multi-label data representation. Sequence of sequences are no longer supported; use a binary array or sparse matrix instead.
```

Any ideas on how I can calculate annotator agreement on this set?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cohen's Kappa does not support multi-label input. Instead of using Cohen's Kappa, one could use Krippendorff's Alpha. This measure supports inter-rater agreement, missing values and non-exclusive topics. It is available on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/krippendorff/).

Answer (score 5):

The specific error is due to an unsupported representation of multi-label output (see documentation of [`type_of_target`](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.multiclass.type_of_target.html) function of sklearn).
Even the correct multi-label output you would still get an error since `cohen_kappa_score` does not support multi-label input (see below). In fact, [Cohen's kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa) *can be applied for multi-class problems only for **exclusive** classes*, and multi label output is by definition non exclusive.

What you could do is have a binary classifier for each label and compute Cohen's kappa for each label. If you need a unique number representing agreement you could compute the average kappa over the labels.

### Example: Cohen's kappa for multi label

```
to_dict = lambda x: {k: [1 if k in y else 0 for y in x] for k in labels}
a_dict = to_dict(annotator_a)
b_dict = to_dict(annotator_b)
cohen_dict = {k: cohen_kappa_score(a_dict[k], b_dict[k]) for k in labels}
cohen_avg = np.mean(list(cohen_dict.values()))

print(f'a_dict: {a_dict}')
print(f'b_dict: {b_dict}')
print(f'cohen_dict: {cohen_dict}')
print(f'cohen_avg: {cohen_avg}')
```

output:

```
a_dict: {'a': [1, 0], 'b': [1, 0], 'c': [1, 0], 'd': [0, 1], 'e': [0, 1], 'f': [0, 0]}
b_dict: {'a': [0, 0], 'b': [1, 0], 'c': [1, 0], 'd': [0, 0], 'e': [0, 0], 'f': [0, 1]}
cohen_dict: {'a': 0.0, 'b': 1.0, 'c': 1.0, 'd': 0.0, 'e': 0.0, 'f': 0.0}
cohen_avg: 0.3333333333333333
```

#### how to transform to sequence of sequence to correct multi label representation

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
m = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=list('abcdef'))
a_multi = m.fit_transform(annotator_a)
b_multi = m.fit_transform(annotator_b)
print(f'a_multi:\n{a_multi}')
print(f'b_multi:\n{b_multi}')
cohen_kappa_score(a_multi, b_multi)
```

output:

```
a_multi:
[[1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 0]]
b_multi:
[[0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1]]
...
ValueError: multilabel-indicator is not supported
```

Answer (score 1):

Although original Cohen's Kappa statistic does not support multiple labels, there are proposed extensions to address this case. By assigning weights to each label, Kappa values allows one to analyze the contribution of primary and secondary (and potentially more) categories to agreement scores. For details, refer to the [Augmenting the kappa statistic to determine interannotator reliability for multiply labeled data points](https://aclanthology.org/N04-4020/) paper.

Of course, one could also use [Krippendorff's alpha reliability coefficient](https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1043&context=asc_papers), which applies to any number of annotators and categories. The weighted Kappa mentioned above is still limited to pairs of labelers.